# How to "share" an Azure website or service between accounts

Tags: azure, service, share

A few of us at my company would like to start using Azure, however.. we are not quite sure of how to set it up..

We would like to have one person administrating the subscription then share that subscription between three other azure accounts.
I read something regarding subscription administrators and co-administrators that sounds to fit my needs for this.

However..
One thing that I cant quite figure out.. is how do we "share"/grant access to multiple websites between our accounts?
Lets setup an scenario..
User 1 creates a website thats hosted in Azure, since User 1 will be on vacation for multiple months, and wont be able to access the azure portal User 2 needs access to this site for maintaining it.
Either User 1 could give User 2 all his credential info for logging into User 1 Azure account, or is there anyway to "share" the created website so two accounts can administrate and maintain the same website?

Any ideas?

Br,
Inx

Answer (score 1):

You just need to give permission for other users to access your subscription and that's it. Once they log into Azure they will see their subscription (if any) and yours to select from (top bar).

**Add a co-administrator to an Azure subscription**

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/gg456328.aspx